# Equivalent of Jacobi elliptic functions

Tags: calculus, limits, special-functions, elliptic-functions

> I would like to compute the equivalent function when $k\rightarrow 0$ of 
>   $$\frac{1}{k}\,\left(\,Z(\frac{u}{k},k) - dn(\frac{u}{k},k)\,\right)$$  where $k$ is the modulus of the Jacobi
>   elliptic function $dn$ and $Z$ the elliptic functions of second
>   species Zeta and $u$ a real variable.

Numerically the limit exists but I can't find any reference for help.
I look into the Lawden's book, I find this kind of relation:
$dn (\frac{u}{k},k)= cn(u,\frac{1}{k})$ but the schmilblick is still at the same place.

[image: k=0.1]

[image: k=0.01]

Note that:
$dn^2(u/k,k) = 1-k^2sn^2(u/k,k)$ and $sn(u/k,k)$ bounded so $1/k\,dn^2(u/k,k)$ behaves like $1/k$ when $k\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I solved the part of the dn function, the Zeta function is still arcane for me

Comment: This is the time in my life I hear about the *schmilblick* in mathematics. But it is very illustrative of the problem. Cheers.

Comment: Try using the definition $$Z(u,k)=\Big(1-\frac EK\Big)u-\int_0^uk^2\operatorname{sn}^2(v,k)\,dv.$$